# Download a PDF file in Node and redirect into front end React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Can you help me to download a file in Node.js and redirect page into the front end? I am using MERN stack (Mongo, Express, React, Node).

After authenticating with the Google Auth, I want to download a file in Node, then I want to redirect the page.

```
router.get(
    '/auth/google/callback',
    passportGoogle.authenticate('google', {
        failureRedirect: '/',
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        try {
          var file = 'resume.pdf';
          res.download(file, (err => {
          if (err) {
                console.log(err)
          } else {
                window.location.href = '/';
          }
        }));
    }
);
```

I tried this code, but after downloading it's not redirecting page to front end.

Answer (score 0):

```
   (req, res) => {
        try {
          var file = 'resume.pdf';
          res.download(file, (error => {
          if (!error) {
              window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
          } else {
                console.log(error)
          }
        }));
    } 
            catch {
                    console.log(error)
    }
```

Comment: Its not working `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Since the headers are already sent with the download response, you'll have to go different route than this.

You'll need to change the response yourself.

```
var data = //filedata
res.set({
    Content-Type: 'text/plain',
    Location: '/'
});
res.end(data);
```

Utilize the Location header accordingly for your redirect.
On the **client**, you'll want to use:

```
window.location.replace("/headerLocation");
```

You want to use this on the client after the success of your callback to your download pdf method.

The reason your getting window undefined is because you're attempting to execute this on your nodejs server. The window object exists on the client.

Comment: We can't send two response to Front end `res.download(file, (err => {` `res.redirect('/desiredURL');`

Comment: Edited my answer. So basically you wherever you request from, add some logic to redirect to the Location header.

Comment: Simple syntax issue... Just add ) after the last curly bracket in the code I added.... If you don't have a good feel for javascript you may have some trouble with the solution I offered. You'll probably also need to set the Content-Type. I'll edit my answer and give you a bit more to go off of.

Comment: There's a couple of issues here. Syntax is one. Within Content-Type, you have a space after Content-, this is causing your code to break. However, I think the main issue here is a lack in fundamental understanding of the framework and language you are utilizing. I can't walk you through the entire ordeal. Your understanding of node.js and javascript should really be a bit better before embarking on a project such as this. However, if you post your client code that calls the api, this would help as well.